# Integration with Google map

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I want to integrate our system with google map.
Like if address found in the system it should locate address in google map.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have looked into the new [maps & location](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_maps.htm) feature introduced in Spring 15 .

Once you enable it, you will see a map tiled section with the address pinned on it just below the address fields. Clicking the map tile will open Google Maps in a new tab.

If the standard maps doesn't fit ur goals, you can look into using the [Visualforce map components](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_vf_mapping_components.htm) to come up with your custom implementation.